# tflint on Visual Studio Code: lint: Linting failed for <path/to/code> TypeError: issues.forEach is not a function

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run `Terraform: Lint` in Visual Studio Code I get the following Output:

```
[ERROR] <cmd>lint: Linting failed for <path/to/code> TypeError: issues.forEach is not a function
```

Note that I don't get this when I run `tflint` from the command line.

Any suggestions what the problem might be?

Comment: How do you run tflint from the command line? Can you post the parts of the code the error is coming from?